# How to prevent password dialog when password login failed

Tags: security, browser

OK, I've built a login where three attempts are permitted. Each works as intended and when uname or pwd fails the login is shown again with the heading '2 login attempts remaining' or 'one more attempt remaining'.

That's working OK.

However, when the 3rd login attempt fails, I have made a message display saying (like) 'login has failed and account has been locked for 30mins. You have been emailed with a message with instructions on what to do next'.

That all works but, when the login has failed and is locked, I don't want the save password dialog to pop up, because it is a failed login. It seems the dialog is triggered by a browser response from the submission of (input type='password') from the login script, rather than a browser response in the authentication script.

Is it possible to prevent that dialog showing (without adjusting an individual's browser settings) or, would it be better that I redirect to a new 'password_locked' script, which didn't receive any pwd data and none was submitted from the redirect instruction?

Not sure that any code will help though I shall post if you need it.